# Android sqlite UPDATE efficiency is low

Tags: android, sqlite

My problem seems wired.

I have a sqlite database when contains about 2500 rows. When I execute the following:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(column, 0);
db.update(table, values, null, null);
```

It costs 3 seconds on average before finishing.

I also tried

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE table SET column = 0");
```

Even longer.

Here is the `.stat` info I got when I executed same command on PC:

```
sqlite> .stat on
sqlite> UPDATE table SET column = 0;
Memory Used:                         10322672 (max 12336272) bytes
Number of Outstanding Allocations:   2229 (max 2529)
Number of Pcache Overflow Bytes:     10237952 (max 10243072) bytes
Number of Scratch Overflow Bytes:    0 (max 0) bytes
Largest Allocation:                  797509 bytes
Largest Pcache Allocation:           4248 bytes
Largest Scratch Allocation:          0 bytes
Lookaside Slots Used:                16 (max 56)
Successful lookaside attempts:       155
Lookaside failures due to size:      190
Lookaside failures due to OOM:       0
Pager Heap Usage:                    8468392 bytes
Page cache hits:                     87018
Page cache misses:                   16596
Page cache writes:                   13201
Schema Heap Usage:                   5088 bytes
Statement Heap/Lookaside Usage:      2656 bytes
Fullscan Steps:                      2584
Sort Operations:                     0
Autoindex Inserts:                   0
Virtual Machine Steps:               67221
```

Can anyone help me figure out where the problem is and how to solve it ?

Comment: The problem is that you're rewriting the entire table.

Comment: You mean codes above will rewrite the entire table instead of just the specific column? Can you explain it more specificly or teach me how to solve the problem?

Comment: Why are you updating all rows?

Comment: This column is used as a sign to mark which row has been modified. When everything finishes, I need to change them all to 0 to be prepared for next cycle. Since most rows will be modified every cycle, UPDATE those rows only doesn't improve much

Comment: There's nothing much you could do. Try moving the column into a separate table.